# The Select2 plugin not working in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, jquery-select2, laravel-5.4, multi-select

I am using laravel 5.4. Now I am using select2 plugin for displaying my select options at multi-level. Here my code is

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<html lang="">
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="matching_star" class="col-md-4 control-label">Matching Star</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select name="matching_star" class="form-control select2" id="matching-star" multiple>
                                <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
                                <option value="bbb">bbb</option>    
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css') }}" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#matching-star').select2();
</script>

</html>
@endsection
```

My app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]) !!};
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
   <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is not working only the input is visible. It suggest nothing when I am click the input. 
If I remove the first line @extends('layouts.app') then it works fine. I think the App.js from App layout override the select2 plugin. How can I implement the multiselect without removing the App layout?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you paste the layouts.app content?

Comment: I have added the App layout. The problem is from the app.js file.

Comment: Well .. try to include that file too then, I dont think someone can guess what's in there..

Comment: Are you getting any errors on browser console?

Comment: No.. I didn't get any error. The input is visible but no suggestion

Answer (score 0):

wrap your javascript in a document ready like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#matching-star').select2();
});
</script>
```

Comment: After adding I got this "TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

1) Please check your select jQuery OR jQuery.min is properly load or Not.

2) Other wise jQuery are twice on your page.

i am not sure but just check it. i hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Remove following from view and check again:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

As far as I know Laravel's default app.js includes jQuery by default.